# How do I assign an Excel VBA variable to a Defined Name

Tags: vba, function, excel

How do I return a value from a VBA Function variable to a Defined Name in Excel 2010?

In the example below, I want `i` to be returned to Excel as a Defined Name `Value_Count` that can be reused in other formulas, such that if `MsgBox` shows 7, then typing `=Value_Count` in a cell would also return 7.

Everything else below is about what I've tried, and why I'd like to do it. If it's inadvisable, I'd be happy to know why, and if there's a better method.

```
Function process_control_F(raw_data As Variant)
Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
For Each cell In raw_data
    i = i + 1
    Next cell
MsgBox i
End Function
```

My goal is to have the value returned by the MsgBox be returned instead to a Defined Name that can be reused in other forumulas.  However, I cannot get the value to show.  I have tried a variety of forms (too numerous to recall, let alone type here) similar to

```
Names.Add Name:="Value_Count", RefersTo:=i
```

I am trying to accomplish this without returning a ton of extra info to cells, just to recall it, hence the desire to return straight to a Defined Name.

I'm using a Function rather than Sub to streamline my use, but if that's the problem, I can definitely change types.

I am creating a version of a Statistical Control Chart. My desired end result is to capture a data range (generally about 336 values) and apply a series of control rules to them (via VBA), then return any values that fall outside of the control parameters to Defined Names that can then be charted or otherwise manipulated.

I've seen (and have versions of) spreadsheets that accomplish this with digital acres of helper columns leading to a chart and summary statistics.  I'm trying to accomplish it mostly in the background of VBA, to be called via Defined Names to Charts — I just can't get the values from VBA to the Charts.

The interest in using a Function rather than a Sub was to streamline access to it.  I'd rather not design a user interface (or use one), if I can just keystroke the function into a cell and access the results directly.  However, as pointed out by Jean-François Corbett, this is quickly turning into a circuitous route to my goal.  However, I still think it is worthwhile, because in the long-term I have a lot of iterations of this analysis to perform, so some setup time is worth it for future time savings.

Comment: The beauty of a function is that it returns its own value XD If you don't want it to return to a cell, why use defined name instead of variable? `x=process_control_F` would work if you set `process_control_F =i`

Comment: Can you clarify a little what you're trying to do, overall?  With the answer below it looks like there's still a little confusion.  Could you explain a little more the big picture, and hopefully we won't end up with an ["XY problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If you type `=Value_Count` in a cell, how is it going to know what the `raw_data` input is supposed to be in order to calculate `i`? Your proposed approach of shoving a function return value into a defined name makes no sense to me. I can't help. There is certainly a way to accomplish your goal (which is still not clear to me) but it sure ain't this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With minor changes to your function, you can use its return value to accomplish what you want:

```
Function process_control_F(raw_data As Variant) As Integer ' <~~ explicit return type
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cell As Variant ' <~~~~ declare variable "cell"
    i = 0
    For Each cell In raw_data
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
    process_control_F = i ' <~~~~ returns the value i
End Function
```

You can then use that function in formulas. For example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I've already cleaned up the code based on what you added (I'm new and self-taught with VBA-a dangerous combination).  Do you have any thoughts on driving the value to a Defined Name?  That's the real crux of my issue.  Many thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Not clear what you're trying to achieve. Sounds like you're probably trying to do something in a very contrived way. Please edit your question to describe exactly what you are trying to achieve with this.